# JSF - Spring JDBC Template

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-jdbc, icefaces-3

When I'm trying to use Spring JDBC Template with JSF/ICEFaces, it throws some errors.

Here is my `spring.xml`

```
<beans ...>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" />
        <property name="username" value="hr" />
        <property name="password" value="hr" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="testDAO" class="com.sura2k.TestDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the DAO.

```
public class TestDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements TestDAO {


    @Override
    public int getTotal(){

        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER"; 
        int total = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);     
        return total;
    }
}
```

Exceptions...

```
....

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[META-INF/database/spring.datasource.xml]: Error setting property values; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; 
nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:

PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: 
Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class 
[oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

...
```

Comment: You need to include the jar that contains the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.  It should go in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Yes you need to have oracle jdbc driver in your classpath.

Comment: @Joe: Solved! I just added the jar file into eclipse Java Build Path. Why doesn't work that?

Comment: That could work too.  I saw you were doing a web application and that's where your jars should end up in a deployment.

Comment: I thought eclipse handles that for us :( You saved my time. Thank you!

Comment: still are you getting error? or Your problem is solved .

Comment: @Boss: Solved! I have another thing to know. Currently I do not inject DAO objects. I use `ApplicationContext.getBean()` instead of that. I got some trouble with injecting spring beans in to JSF ManagedBeans. Is it ok to use `ApplicationContext.getBean()` without injecting?

Comment: @sura2k. yep you can use that but if you autowire bean then its much more simpler